# Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

Tags: jasmine, webdriver, jasmine-node, chrome-web-driver

When I run my webdriverjs, jasmine-node tests I am getting following error.

```
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://172.19.35.25:4444/wd/hub
at Error (<anonymous>)
at onResponse (/mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:87:11)
at /mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:42:21
at /mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/http/http.js:96:5
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:145:7)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1551:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:440:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

==== async task ====

```
WebElement.click()
    at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:302:15)
    at webdriver.WebElement.schedule_ (/mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1665:23)
    at webdriver.WebElement.click (/mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1770:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/javascript-framework/JSTESTING/Jasmine2/jasmine2-standalone/spec/ospFunctionalTestSpec.js:91:96)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I have tried following options but no luck

```
jasmine.getEnv().defaultTimeoutInterval = 600000;
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(300000);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(600000);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(7200000);
```

Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Is your server up? You can check it at `http://172.19.35.25:4444/wd/hub/status` and whether your nodes are registered `http://172.19.35.25:4444/grid/console`. If both are good, what is the selenium server version and browser you are using?